# Is there a name for this knapsack-like problem?

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is as follows:

1. You have X piles of different fruit (so apples in one pile, bananas in another, etc.)
2. Each individual fruit has a known tastyness and weight
3. You must pick one fruit from each pile
4. You must pick the tastiest combination
5. The total weight of your combination cannot exceed a certain number

So its similar to the knapsack problem in the way that you have to pick the best combination without breaching the weight limit but different in the way where you must pick one item each from separate collections.

I'm trying to build an efficient solver for this problem but before I get into it, I was wondering if theres a specific name for it so I could check out what other people have done.

Comment: Your "taste" and "weight" correspond to "value" and "weight" in the [usual formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) of the knapsack problem, so the new element in your problem is just the different piles. The piles can be encoded as additional digits in the value/weight inputs, so there's an easy reduction back to the usual knapsack problem.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that is true but the fact that they need to be from different piles allows for some optimization, currently I'm ordering each of the piles by their value and filtering out items that don't yield an improvement of value with additional weight and then brute-force balancing first 2 sets at the time, then 3...X. I don't know how to express the complexity of this algorithm but its far quicker than O(nW)

Comment: You can reduce both ways, so your problem is just as NP-complete as the knapsack problem in general. If you have an algorithm with _guaranteed_ good behavior on all instances, you'll be famous.